# Firefox extensions development with mootools

Tags: firefox, mootools, browser-extension

Is it feasible to develop extensions with mootools?

Comment: i never heard about a mootools solution but there is a development framework called [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) where you can do exactly what you are looking for only with jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy was doing it with Jetpack: 
https://builder.mozillalabs.com/user/4994829/

Comment: awesome - although - are there plans to make jetpack a stock plugin?

Comment: It is already in beta. The Addon-builder needs another plugin to maintain testing, but if one would download the xpi and install in FF it will work without restarting.

Comment: what i meant was, jetpack will be a part of a standard FF 4 download, right?

Comment: Really cool. I will try Jetpack right now. Thanks for the tip. https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/